# How do you use/make a custom widget in kivy language, but with python code?

Tags: python, kivy

I want to be able to use my custom (python written) widget in both the kv file and in python code. I don't know how to create a widget, then use it in my chosen layout.

```
class SelectableList(FocusBehavior, CompoundSelectionBehavior, StackLayout):
    previous_nodes=[]
    # this class has a whole bunch of "def's" that I got rid of so that stack would let me post a shorter question

class myScreen(Screen):
    def build(self):
        self.root_boi = StackLayout(size=(1,1))
        stack = SelectableList(touch_multiselect=True,
                               multiselect=True)
        for i in range(0, 6):
            stack.add_widget(Button(size_hint_y=None, height=30, text="Button {0}".format(i)))
        self.root_boi.add_widget(stack)
        return self.root_boi

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(myScreen(name='whatever you want it to be...'))
        return myScreen()

TestApp().run()
```

I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong here. I'm trying to add the "SelectableList" widget into a stack layout. I want to be able to add it to whatever widget I choose, either within a kv file or in my python code. If that makes sense...

Comment: What is happening that you didn't expect to happen? Also you create the variable `sm` in your build method but then don't do anything with it, so if you're expecting that to be displayed then that's your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your `build()` method of `myScreen` should actually be an `__init__()` method (with no return). I added `self.add_widget(self.root_boi)` in place of the `return`. And the class name should be capitalized (`MyScreen`), since the `kv` language gets fussy about that sometimes.

Here is a modified version of your code that demonstrates using your custom widgets:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior, CompoundSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout


class SelectableList(FocusBehavior, CompoundSelectionBehavior, StackLayout):
    previous_nodes=[]
    # this class has a whole bunch of "def's" that I got rid of so that stack would let me post a shorter question

class MyScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.root_boi = StackLayout(size=(1,1))
        stack = SelectableList(touch_multiselect=True,
                               multiselect=True)
        for i in range(0, 6):
            stack.add_widget(Button(size_hint_y=None, height=30, text="Button {0}".format(i)))
        self.root_boi.add_widget(stack)
        self.add_widget(self.root_boi)

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

kv = '''
# ScreenManager:
#     MyScreen:
#
#    or
#
ScreenManager:
    Screen:
        name: 'whatever'
        StackLayout:
            SelectableList:
                touch_multiselect: True
                multiselect: True
                Button:
                    text: 'Button 0'
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: 30
                Button:
                    text: 'Button 1'
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: 30
                Button:
                    text: 'Button 2'
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: 30
'''
TestApp().run()
```

The `__init__()` method of `MyScreen` must include a call to the `super` `__init__()`.

The `kv` string in the above code shows two different uses of your custom widgets. The first (commented out) uses the `MyScreen` custom widget. The second (not commented out) uses the `SelectableList` custom widget.

Comment: Thank you so much! The missing part was the super __init__(). I don't have trouble integrating this widget in the kv file (I learned after trying it), but I have trouble testing custom widgets in a separate "test.py" to quickly check functionality. This worked though! Thanks again